# The prime numbers between 1 and 100

Tags: functions

I'm new on this and the help seems not as helpful on this particular subject
The prime numbers between 1 and 100 mathematica show steps

Comment: – "the help seems not as helpful on this particular subject". On the contrary, simply searching for [prime numbers](http://reference.wolfram.com/search/?q=prime%20numbers) gives you all the information you need.

Comment: The first example in the reference for `Prime` is: `Table[Prime[n], {n, 25}]`

Comment: thank you very much.Does this answer mathematica programs.?

Comment: Your question seems to ask to find those integers from 1 to 100 that are prime. A direct translation of the question into *Mathematica* code gives an answer: `Select[Range[100], PrimeQ]`

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
t=Table[FactorInteger[k],{k,1,100}] (* show the factors *)  
Cases[t,{{_,1}}]  (* select only those with one factor with exponent 1 *)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `PrimePi` to find how many primes are less than 100

```
Array[Prime, PrimePi[100]]
```

Comment: He doesn't "need". But certainly he "could"